# Can articles be used with adjectives?

Tags: grammar

I saw a video
In which the girl says *I think I can smell the spiritual*

As far as I know articles can not be used with adjectives . No?

Comment: Do not post the same question multiple times. If you need to add more information, the correct thing to do is to edit your existing question.

Answer (score 0):

*"I can smell the spiritual"* is slang. She used an adjective as a noun, which is grammatically incorrect in this particular case. But like I said, it's slang.

Comment: https://m.9gag.com/gag/aGeAxDw